# Check for partial match in JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter, partial

I've got elements set up something like this:

```
<div class="cat" data-cat="example-cat, test-cat, test-category">
    ...
</div>
<div class="cat" data-cat="test-category">
    ...
</div>
<div class="cat">
    ...
    <div class="cat" data-cat="example-cat, test-category">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="cat" data-cat="test-category, one-more-cat">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Using JavaScript, I need to check each bit of text between commas for a match with a user selected value. For example, if the user selected "test-cat," I need to check each `div` to see if `data-cat` matches the selection. If it does, I need to add `class="active"` to each matching `div`.

Part of the trick is that if the user selects `test-cat`, a `div` with a `data-cat` of `test-category` should not return positive. Only exact matches should be consider matches.

---

I had already set up a complex filtering system with support for multiple filters, but the client wants to be able to set multiple categories per div, which is making this tricky. I have a script set up to show matches if the attribute is an exact match, and I'll be trying to modify this to work as I need it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changedOnce = false;
    $("#filters select").change(function() {
        $(".cat").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("data-match", "true");
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        });
        $("#filters select").each(function() {
            var filter = $(this).attr("name");
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(".cat").each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("data-match") === "false") {
                    return true;
                }
                var attr = $(this).attr("data-" + filter);
                var childAttr = $(this).find(".cat").attr("data-" + filter)
                if ((typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) || (typeof childAttr !== typeof undefined && childAttr !== false)) {
                    if ($(this).attr("data-" + filter) === value || $(this).find(".cat").attr("data-" + filter) === value || value === "") {
                        $(this).attr("data-match", "true");
                        $(this).parents(".cat").attr("data-match", "true");
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("data-match", "false");
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (value !== "") {
                        $(this).attr("data-match", "false");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("data-match", "true");
                        $(this).parents(".cat").attr("data-match", "true");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

My filters are set up something like:

```
<div id="filters">
    <select name="cat">
        <option value="test-cat">Test Cat</option>
        <option value="example-cat">Example Cat</option>
        ...
    </select>
    ...
    <select name="nth-filter">
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution (I'm no JavaScript master), but it was working, until I made this most recent change. If you need more information, just let me know.

---

UPDATE: Here's my current script, using `.data()` and `.split()` as suggested. I'm having trouble getting the parent category to show as a miss if all its children are misses, but I'll post a separate question for that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filters select").change(function() {
        $(".cat").each(function() {
            $(this).data("match", true);
            $(this).css("opacity", "1");
            // $(this).removeClass("open");
        });
        $("#filters select").each(function() {
            var filter = $(this).attr("name");
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(".cat").not(".primary").each(function() {
                if ($(this).data(filter)) {
                    var match = $(this).data("match");
                    var attributes = $(this).data(filter).split(", ");
                    var i = 0;
                    $(attributes).each(function() {
                        if (value && attributes[i] !== value) {
                            match = false;
                        } else {
                            match = true;
                            return true;
                        }
                        i++;
                    });
                    $(this).data("match", match);
                }
                if ($(this).data("match") === false) {
                    $(this).css("opacity", "0.25");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should probably be accessing your `data-` attributes via the jQuery `.data()` API. If you do that, and you format the `data-cat` values as JSON arrays of strings, jQuery will even parse the JSON for you so that you have an array of strings to search through with `.indexOf()`.

Comment: split on comma and use inArray to test. Simpler yet, use classes and .hasClass instead of the attr

Comment: @Pointy++: it's worth noting though that using regex might be a better fit here, otherwise we need to use workarounds whenever our matching might get more complicated (most common: case-insensitive matching - with `.indexOf()` we'd have to use `.toLowerCase()` on all strings matched both with and against). If @Pointy comment is not enough, fiddle would be much appreciated - then it would be much easier for us to alter given code to match this specific use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String's `split` function to split the comma-separated values into an array, and then use the Array's `indexOf` function to check for a match.

```
var attr = $(this).attr("data-" + filter);

if (attr && (attr.split(/[\s*,\s*]+/).indexOf() >= 0)) {
```

---

Note: I left out this part of the check: `attr !== false`. `attr` should either be a String or undefined, so it will never be `false`. Did you mean to check if it is the string `"false"`?

---

Also, when you call the following:

```
var childAttr = $(this).find(".cat").attr("data-" + filter)
```

You should be aware that `.attr()` will return the value of the first matched element, and from your markup it looks like there could be multiple matched elements.